# Installing cvxopt

Tags: python, cvxopt

I have some problems when installing this package

> c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging1.tmp\cvxopt\src\c\cvxopt.h(31) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'complex.h': No such file or directory error: command 
>   C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

- > You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 8.1.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a solution for using CVXOPT quickly, I would recommend installing the anaconda Python distribution.

It is free and has very good features for installing and managing 3rd party packages.

[Download anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and follow the installation instructions. Then, you can install CVXOPT with a command like the following.

```
$ conda install cvxopt
```

CVXOPT will work along side numpy.